# Regex parse query string with ampersand in value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm getting query string from 3-rd party service and ampersand in value is not encoded there, so my case is:

```
param1=test&param2=cpd&cpd&param3=abc
```

so I need to get it like

```
param1 = test
param2 = cpd&cpd
param3 = abc
```

because it's not encoded **I can't use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(str)**; because it's split my value **cpd&cpd** as parameter. So I'm trying to write some regex that I can use.
I wrote this:

```
(&|)(\w*)=
```

But it helps me only to get parameters names like param1, param3 etc...
I'm sure that there should be some good regex to split it correctly, I see anchor **=cpd&cpd&** it should like take everything to the last ampersand in group. But my regex knowledges is really bad...

Comment: Please use an actual URL parser, not Regex. If your param value has a `&` in it, and it's not escaped, it's invalid.

Comment: I just answered in post that I can't use actual URL parser, because I'm getting this string from 3-rd party service and they didn't encode ampersand in parameter's value

Comment: Can you fix the garbage data you're getting?

Comment: no unfortunately...

Comment: Give up this bad 3rd party service. | Show us how you get this query string. I suspect that decoding ampersand is taking place at the receiving stage.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov it's just a row in their database "param1=test&param2=cpd&cpd&param3=abc"